Can i use same cl::program for different contexts on same device
I process some data in realtime with opencl and send that data to opengl widget. I have many opengl widgets, so i forced to create many opencl contexts. Creating program in opencl requires context. So, i compile same opencl program many times (to each widget) and that is the reason why my app starts incredibly slow. Is it possible to compile opencl program only once for same device?

Why don't you just have one program and context and use multiple kernels?

Because opengl <-> opencl interop requires unique opencl context for each opengl window. So many windows means many opencl contexts for them.

I see. Have you tried building from binary instead of from source?

Not yet.This looks like the right solution, but i am new in opencl and I haven't figured out how to do it yet.
